# Can't set headers after they're sent

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I have an issue I've seen on here before, but I dont' know why it's happening in my "app". I am getting the "can't set headers after they're sent" error whenever I just go to the route, `/`. I'm sure I'm missing something basic. I've looked at the documentation and I've looked at other answers here, but I still can't seem to see why this would happen. Can someone please walk through why this error is occuring?

When I change writeHead to setHeader, everything works accordingly. Where else would I have sent the headers other than `/`?

```
// Basic Setup
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, bodyParser = require('body-parser')
, port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Setup Routes
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.json({name: "tester"});
});

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.writeHead('200', {"Content-Type": 'text/html'});
  res.send("<html><head></head><body>Welcome to something. Sent from server.</body>        </html>");
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log("listening on port " + port);`
```

Comment: use res.setHeader instead of res.writeHead

Comment: Thanks @WaqasAhmed, but I'm trying to understand what's going on here, not put a bandaid on it. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SetHeader**:

Sets a single header value for implicit headers. If this header already exists in the to-be-sent headers, it's value will be replaced. Use an array of strings here if you need to send multiple headers with the same name.

As Given Here:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#response.setHeader

**WriteHead** :

Sends a response header to the request. The status code is a 3-digit HTTP status code, like 404. The last argument, headers, are the response headers. Optionally one can give a human-readable reasonPhrase as the second argument.

This method must only be called once on a message and it must be called before response.end() is called.

If you call response.write() or response.end() before calling this, the implicit/mutable headers will be calculated and call this function for you.

As Given Here:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#response.writeHead

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to call `res.setHeader(name, value)` as often as you want until you call `res.writeHead(statusCode)`. After `writeHead`, the headers are baked in and you can only call `res.write(data)`, and finally `res.end(data)`.

Try this:

```
Any exceptions within middleware function(req, res, next) (Connect/Express only)
res.send(body|status[, headers|status[, status]]) (Express only)
```